# How to install evince on CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406

Tags: centos, rpm, pdf, evince

On my CentOS Linux release 7.0.1406 the PDF reader doesn't render image colours correctly that's sent from MacOSx/CS Adobe Acrobat.

Is there a way to install Evince with Yum on this particular version; maybe a special repo? or a straight RPM install. Hopefully that's a better PDF reader than the one that's the default PDF reader that's on my current CentOS.

I tried installing it from sourceforge, but I only got a tar.xz file compression which gave me another .tar file which was corrupt.

Comment: What does `yum search evince` show?

Comment: Thanks. It showed evince in the yum search list with all its packages and I installed it. I'm still not sure if its a good PDF reader. When I launch a PDF file it showed the Syntax Warning: Invalid Font Weight 5 times and I'm doubting if its rendering PDF colours correctly or if its a good reader or if there's a better reader out there that's well suited for CentOS?